# Imagestream to file resulting in partially gray image (sometimes)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I having an issue uploading / sending images from a stream to a generic handler in ASP.NET. I’ve build a windows phone app that can take an image and send it to the generic handler on my website.

Unfortunately in some occasions the image turns out to be (partially) gray. I think it might have something to to with a lost/bad internet connection of the mobile device. This problem happens every 50 images or so.

When the faulty image is send I do not get an error of any kind. I’m looking for two possible solutions.

1. How do i prevent the windows phone uploading a partially gray image to the generic handler.
2. How do i check if an image is partially gray on the server so can send a error message back to the phone.

to make this question more compleet I included the code of the generic handler and an example image. Second I’m very curious why this occus. TCPIP has an handshake so above isseu should not be possible ?

```
public class UploadImages : IHttpHandler
{
    private IWorkOrderRepository _workOrderRepository;
    private IDigitalFileRepository _digitalFileRepository;
    private IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public UploadImages()
    {
        _workOrderRepository = ((Global)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance).Kernel.Get<IWorkOrderRepository>();
        _digitalFileRepository = ((Global)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance).Kernel.Get<IDigitalFileRepository>();
        _userRepository = ((Global)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance).Kernel.Get<IUserRepository>();
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        var user = (Domain.Users.User)HttpContext.Current.User;

        string WorkOrderId = context.Request.QueryString["workOrderId"];
        string latitude = context.Request.QueryString["LATITUDE"];
        string Longitude = context.Request.QueryString["LONGITUDE"];

        if (latitude != "0" && Longitude != "0")
        {
            string file = "Filename.jpg";
            string uploadPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/Temp/");
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                var image = ImageResizer.Resize(Image.FromStream(context.Request.InputStream), 700);
                image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                stream.Position = 0;
                var workOrder = _workOrderRepository.GetAll(x => x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(WorkOrderId)).FirstOrDefault();
                workOrder.AddPhoto(_workOrderRepository, _digitalFileRepository, new AuditInfo((Domain.Users.User)user), stream, file, "image/jpeg", Convert.ToDouble(latitude), Convert.ToDouble(Longitude));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string file = "Filename.jpg";
            string uploadPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/Temp/");
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                var image = ImageResizer.Resize(Image.FromStream(context.Request.InputStream), 700);
                image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                stream.Position = 0;
                var workOrder = _workOrderRepository.GetAll(x => x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(WorkOrderId)).FirstOrDefault();
                workOrder.AddPhoto(_workOrderRepository, _digitalFileRepository, new AuditInfo((Domain.Users.User)user), stream, file, "image/jpeg");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example image partially gray]

[image: Example image partially gray]